# SQL Server trace how to see the TSQL for prepared SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run an SQL trace I want to see the TSQL statements that are executed. I chose all the TSQL events to show.  For most like "SQL:StmtStarting" I can see the TSQL but for "Exec prepared SQL" the TextData is blank.

Any ideas? I want to see the query that will be executed.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL:StmtStarting should give you the text of your TSQL every time. You should not even need any of the other options if all you want is to see the TSQL that will be executed? Are you saying that you are running TSQL queries and not seeing them with this option?

Comment: Yeah. I have a parameterized query and I do not see it when I use "SQL:StmtStarting". When I add "Exec prepared SQL" I see a record of it but TextData is blank so I'm not 100% sure that's the query I'm looking at.

Comment: It's just a select from a JDBC driver - select * from table where id = ?

Comment: What about under Stored Procedures RPC:Starting? It might be the way that the JDBC driver is pushing it through?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the JDBC. I'll check that.

Answer (score 1):

I have hunted and hunted for a way to handle this without any luck.  The only way I've found is to find the earlier sp_prepare statement in the trace.

I wrote a utility to summarize traces files ([ClearTrace](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/)).  It handles matching sp_prepare statements to the later executions of those statements where they don't cross trace file boundries.